# Downloading files via PHP problem on webserver

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdf, download

Could someone help me with a little PHP problem?

This is my code:

```
$mr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ms);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($mr['flink']) . "\""); 
readfile($mr['flink']);
header("Location: ref.php?action=viewdeti&id=".$_GET['id']);
```

Where $mysqli is my mysql connection and $id is $_GET['id'].

$mr['flink'] is link to file hosted on my server.

Now the problem:

When the code is hosted on my server the code runs successful and allow to download the file from localhost and redirect me to correct page.

When the code is hosted on web server hosting and when run the script don't download the file hosted on the web server but opens the file in browser as code and doesn't redirect me.

I will attach photos to see the problem in fact.

The versions on server's apache, mysql, php is same as on the localhost.

The files for downloading are *.pdf

Please if you have any idea, help me.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Rossen

[WEB SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MojnA.png)
[LOCALHOST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKGZO.png)

Comment: What happens if you use content-type `application/pdf` (for PDF documents) instead of `application/octet-stream` (for "I don't know what this is, but it's probably something binary")?

Comment: If that doesn't matter, it's possible the server has error reporting enabled. That `header('Location: ...')` at the end should trigger a "Warning: headers already sent" message from PHP, that you might have hidden on your local server (if this is the case, it should be visible at the very end of that binary PDF data you see when you try to download the file from the server).

Answer (score 0):

```
$mr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ms);

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  // mainly for Gecko browsers
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($mr['flink'])) . ' GMT');   // modified date of file, useful with caching 
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // To resume download
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($mr['flink']));  // file size
header('Content-Encoding: none');    // don't worry about encoding
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');  // mime type if the file is PDF, change if required
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($mr['flink']));  // force browser to show the Save As dialog
readfile($mr['flink']);  // actually download the file, required
header("Location: ref.php?action=viewdeti&id=".$_GET['id']);    // copied from question
```

Each line has comment which is explained.

Along with the above, make sure that the actual file has .pdf extension. It somehow appears that the file is missing the extension on your remote server.

Comment: I tried but it's the same. If I copy direct link to the browser it's open the real content of pdf. And the link is correct recorded in DB correct. When I print($mr['flink']) it's returns me link of the file hosted on the server. If I copy link and I paste in the new browser's tab it's opens the pdf file absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Now already working properly. I recompile it via UTF8 without B

```
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($mr['flink'])) . ' GMT'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($mr['flink']));
```

And now it's ok.

Thanks all for help.